# monogo not install on ubuntu

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, sudo

When I try to install Mongo with the following commands, I encounter the following message in the update section:

```
$ wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-3.4.asc | sudo apt-key add -
$ echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org curl
```

---

Error On SSH
, Ubuntu 16.04

```
root@karafarinyar:~# sudo apt-get update
sudo: unable to resolve host karafarinyar
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/bigbluebutton/support/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:2 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 InRelease
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:5 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 Release
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Ign:7 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:10 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:11 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse all Packages
Hit:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Ign:13 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse Translation-en_US
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rmescandon/yq/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:15 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:7 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:11 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse all Packages
Ign:13 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign:15 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:7 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse arm64 Packages
Hit:16 https://ubuntu.bigbluebutton.org/xenial-22 bigbluebutton-xenial InRelease
Ign:11 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse all Packages
Hit:17 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_8.x xenial InRelease
Ign:13 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign:15 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:7 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:11 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse all Packages
Ign:13 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign:15 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:7 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:11 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse all Packages
Ign:13 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign:15 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse Translation-en
Err:7 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse amd64 Packages
  403  Forbidden [IP: 13.33.242.42 80]
Ign:10 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:11 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse all Packages
Ign:13 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign:15 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 13.33.242.42 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I want to install the following software
https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/2.2/install.html

Comment: Can you clarify what are you trying to install? MongoDB or Big Blue Button?

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your command, the line:

```
$ echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list
```

has an incorrect path for the MongoDB repository, it should be `http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/`